# How can I make this as optimisticResponse?

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma

I have a "like" button/mutation. There is still a split second while I get a response from the server. How can I make this as an `optimisticResponse`?

Here's my mutation:

```
const LIKE_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation LIKE_MUTATION($postId: ID!) {
    createLike(postId: $postId) {
      id
      post {
        id
        title
        text
        createdAt
        author {
          id
        }
        likes {
          id
          user {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Now what I'm trying to do in my Mutation component is:

```
optimisticResponse={{
  __typename: 'Mutation',
  createLike: {
    __typename: 'Like',
    id: this.props.post.id,
    post: this.props.post,
    likes: this.props.post.likes.concat({
      id: 'vcjsvdcjscd',
      user: { name: 'sample', id: 'jsdckbsdjcbdjs' },
    }),
  },
}}
```

the like is connected to `post` and to `user` in my schema. I'm trying to provide fake user `id` and `name` here. It doesn't work. I get this in the console as well:

```
Missing field id in {
  "name": "user",
  "__typename": "User"
}
```